# Describing the first few evaluation steps of a given foldr function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The following function is given:

```
mystery a b c xs = 
  foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + c)) (\a b -> a + b - c) xs a b
```

I know what the function does roughly but I have a hard time really understanding the intermediate steps. I picked following example:

```
mystery 1 2 3 [1, 2, 3]
```

Especially the use of `rec` is giving me a hard time. I assume that one of the final steps looks like this:

```
(\a b -> 3 + (b + 3 + 3 + 3) - 3) [] 1 2
```

So the output is `11`. Could someone describe the first few steps of the execution? What happens after:

```
foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + 3)) (\a b -> a + b - 3) [1, 2, 3] 1 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is that the foldr operation is constructing a function, *then* applying it to a and b; we can clarify it by adding parentheses:

```hs
mystery a b c xs = 
(foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + c)) (\a b -> a + b - c) xs) a b
```

If the xs list is empty, you get simply the initial function `\a b -> a + b - c`, which is then applied to a and b.

if it is not empty, then it makes succesive transformations to that function (in each iteration, "rec" is the previous function, which is used to construct a new one).

To illustrate, let's run the foldr by hand for `mystery 1 2 3 [1, 2, 3]`;
initially, we have:

```hs
foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + 3)) (\a b -> a + b - 3) [1,2,3]
```

Applying the equations for foldr:

```hs
foldr f z []     = z 
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Reduces the expression to:

```hs
(\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + 3)) (\a b -> a + b - 3) [2,3])
```

Repeating for the next value in the list we get:

```hs
(\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 2 (b + 3)) (foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + 3)) (\a b -> a + b - 3) [3])
```

Then, for the last one:

```hs
(\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 2 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 3 (b + 3)) (\a b -> a + b - 3)
```

We need to compose those functions, to create the final function - replacing "rec" with the previous function:

```hs
(\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 2 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 3 (b + 3)) (\a b -> a + b - 3)
=> (\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 2 (b + 3)) (\a b -> (\a b -> a + b - 3) 3 (b + 3))
=> (\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\rec a b -> rec 2 (b + 3)) (\a b -> 3 + (b + 3) - 3))
=> (\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\a b -> (\a b -> 3 + (b + 3) - 3)) 2 (b + 3))
=> (\rec a b -> rec 1 (b + 3)) (\a b -> 3 + ((b + 3) + 3) - 3))
=> \a b -> (\a b -> 3 + ((b + 3) + 3) - 3)) 1 (b + 3)
=> \a b -> 3 + (((b + 3) + 3) + 3) - 3)
=> \a b -> b + 9
```

then, we apply `\a b -> b + 9` to the original "a" and "b" (which are 1 and 2), and get 2 + 9 = 11

Answer (score 3):

Substituting the definition for `foldr`, the function reveals itself to be

```
mystery a b c xs = 
 = foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + c)) (\a b -> a + b - c) xs a b
 = let { g x r   a b =  r   x (b + c); z a b =  a + b - c } in 
     foldr g z xs a b
     =>  foldr g z [] a b = z a b            = a  + b       - c
     =>  foldr g z [x1,x2,...,xn] a  b
          = g x1 (foldr g z [x2,...,xn]) a b   -- g x r a b = r x (b+c)
          = foldr g z [x2,...,xn] x1 (b+c)
          = foldr g z [x3,...,xn] x2 (b+c*2)
          = foldr g z [         ] xn (b+c*n) = xn + b + c*n - c
 = last (a:xs) + b + c * (length xs - 1)
```

Naming the two lambda functions, using short names, makes it much easier to handle the expressions visually.

Answer (score 0):

When the folding function given to `foldr` takes more than two parameters, it's often really a `foldl` in disguise. Let's see if that's true here.

```
mystery a b c xs = foldr (\x rec a b -> rec x (b + c)) (\a b -> a + b - c) xs a b
```

Uncurry the two "extra" arguments to the folding function:

```
mystery a b c xs = foldr (\x rec (a,b) -> rec (x,b + c)) (\(a,b) -> a + b - c) xs (a,b)
```

Extract function `f` out of the folding function, and `finalStep` from the nil case:

```
mystery a b c xs = foldr (\x rec z -> rec (f z x)) finalStep xs (a,b)
  where
    f (a,b) x = (x,b + c)
    finalStep (a,b) = a + b - c
```

Replace `foldr` with explicit recursion:

```
mystery a b c xs = go xs (a,b)
  where
    go [] = finalStep
    go (x:xs) = \z -> go xs (f z x)
    f (a,b) x = (x,b + c)
    finalStep (a,b) = a + b - c
```

Move the call to `finalStep` outside of `go`:

```
mystery a b c xs = finalStep $ go xs (a,b)
  where
    go [] = id
    go (x:xs) = \z -> go xs (f z x)
    f (a,b) x = (x,b + c)
    finalStep (a,b) = a + b - c
```

Eta-expand `go` and reverse the order of the arguments:

```
mystery a b c xs = finalStep $ go (a,b) xs
  where
    go z [] = z
    go z (x:xs) = go (f z x) xs
    f (a,b) x = (x,b + c)
    finalStep (a,b) = a + b - c
```

Now, `go` is exactly the definition of `foldl f`, so replace it with that:

```
mystery a b c xs = finalStep $ foldl f (a,b) xs
  where
    f (a,b) x = (x,b + c)
    finalStep (a,b) = a + b - c
```

Now we have a very simple fold operation that can be trivially worked through. The key takeaway from the above is the fact that `foldr (\x rec -> rec . f x) finalStep xs z` and `finalStep $ foldl (flip f) z xs` are the same, for any `f`, `z`, and `xs`.